# CSS transition while keeping the object in center viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css transition on `max-height`

```css
.container {
    max-height: 70vh;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.container .expanded {
    max-height: calc(70vh + 500px);
}
```

I'd like to keep the center of the container in the same place - so effectively have it "collapse down" when the expanded class is removed, but have the bottom of the container remain in the same place in the view port (effectively scrolling the page as it animates)

I've got a somewhat working version of this using JavaScript, like so

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (nextStateIsMinified && this.viewMoreButtonRef && this.viewMoreButtonRef.current) {
        this.viewMoreButtonRef.current.scrollIntoView({
          block: 'end',
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
      }
    }, 100);
```

But it's fairly janky and not a good UX.

Is there a native way to do what I'm trying to do?

Here is an example in CodePen.

https://codepen.io/jonluca/pen/XWJPogj

I'd like to have the button remain in the center of the viewport when you click it.

Comment: Could you make a workable snippet out of your code. It is hard to visualize what you intend and what is going wrong. Images would also help.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier https://codepen.io/jonluca/pen/XWJPogj